# Get data from xml to dataframe (some fields are missing in element/node) need to set default values NA

Tags: r, dataframe, xml2

I am quite new in R and I am struggeling with getting the data in to the dataframe from XML, standard is ok, but some fields are missing so I need to do some iteration to get NA in case of missing field(node). In my example
there are assets and each have information regarding SecurityCodes,.. but in some assets there are some info missing like InterestClaimGross...

```
            <Portfolio>
                <Assets>
                    <SecurityCodes>
                        <ISIN>XS1300502041</ISIN>
                    </SecurityCodes>
                    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                    <NominalOrUnits>2000000</NominalOrUnits>
                    <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
                    <Price>107.233</Price>
                    <MarketValue>
                        <Amount>2144660</Amount>
                        <AmountForeign>2144660</AmountForeign>
                        <AmountCurrency>
                            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                            <Amount>2144660</Amount>
                        </AmountCurrency>
                    </MarketValue>
                    <InterestClaimGross>
                        <Amount>34027.4</Amount>
                        <AmountForeign>34027.4</AmountForeign>
                        <AmountCurrency>
                            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                            <Amount>34027.4</Amount>
                        </AmountCurrency>
                    </InterestClaimGross>

                </Assets>
                 <Assets>
                    <SecurityCodes>
                        <ISIN>XS0953958641</ISIN>
                    </SecurityCodes>
                    <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                    <NominalOrUnits>200000</NominalOrUnits>
                    <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
                    <Price>104.798</Price>
                    <MarketValue>
                        <Amount>209596</Amount>
                        <AmountForeign>209596</AmountForeign>
                        <AmountCurrency>
                            <Currency>EUR</Currency>
                            <Amount>209596</Amount>
                        </AmountCurrency>
                    </MarketValue>
                </Assets>
```

I can get info about (AUV =InterestClaimGross/Amount) for 1st isin.
Total isin are 58 but I get 57 because of following sibling-

I would like to get table:

```
  ISIN          PRICE     AUV
1 XS1300502041 107.233 34027.4
2 XS0953958641 104.798   NA
3...
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is to use the `xmlToDataFrame` function from the XML package:

```
library(XML)

df<-xmlToDataFrame("<Portfolio> <Assets>
               <SecurityCodes>
             ...
               </Assets></Portfolio>")

df
#sample output
 SecurityCodes Currency NominalOrUnits ExchangeRate   Price              MarketValue       InterestClaimGross
1  XS1300502041      EUR        2000000            1 107.233 21446602144660EUR2144660 34027.434027.4EUR34027.4
2  XS0953958641      EUR         200000            1 104.798    209596209596EUR209596                     <NA>
```